# bash: How to prompt for user input while reading file?

Tags: bash, scripting, interactive

Following script statement for user input is nested in while loop under if block but it doesn't work and is being skipped. How do I get user input to work?

`exec 3<&0 && read -p 'Enter your answer: ' uservar <&3`

```
FILE="hostnames.txt"
echo $(sudo chmod +777 $FILE)
echo "Step 1. Checking if file with hostnames exists."

#exec 3<&0

if [ -f "$FILE" ]
then
  echo "PASSED: File hostnames.txt does exist." && echo ""
  while IFS= read -r hostname;
    do
     echo "Step 2. Checking Grph mgmt_con_ip4 exists for $hostname"
     mgmt_con_ip4="$(echo "$(llama-grph node show $hostname | grep mgmt_con_i$
     echo "Grph has management IPv4 address: $mgmt_con_ip4"
     if [ -z $mgmt_con_ip4 ]
       then
         echo "PASSED: Grph mgmt_con_ip4 == NULL" && echo ""
       else
         echo "FAILED: Grph mgmt_con_ip4 == NOT NULL" && echo ""
         echo "$(ipam --format json get-cidr-parent $mgmt_con_ip4)" && echo ""
         echo "WARNING: OOB networks shouldn't have $mgmt_con_ip4 IPv4 addres$
         exec 3<&0 && read -p 'Enter your answer: ' uservar <&3
     fi
  done < $FILE
fi
```

Comment: why? your user input question seem like it should be done **outside** of the while loop - you don't want it to ask for every line of $FILE, do you?  It doesn't even seem to be asking a question, anyway - just stating "FAILED" and "WARNING" and then prompts the user for an answer - an answer to what? there's no question there.

Comment: Other comments: 1. using `sudo chmod 777` to brute-force RWX permissions is a bad idea. If the user running the script should have permission then it should be set up that way in the first place.   2. [quote your variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766) - e.g. `[ -z $mgmt_con_ip4 ]` will be a syntax error if `mgmt_con_ip4` is empty because it will expand to just `[ -z ]`.  use `[ -z "$mgmt_con_ip4" ]` instead. See also [$VAR vs ${VAR} and to quote or not to quote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4899)

Comment: @cas Note: `[ -z ]` is not a syntax error. It should be equivalent to `[ -n -z ]` and this is true, like `[ -z "$mgmt_con_ip4" ]` is when `$mgmt_con_ip4` expands to an empty string. So `[ -z $mgmt_con_ip4 ]` "would work" in case of an empty string; it's still bad code, but the result is as expected. Errors will happen if unquoted `$mgmt_con_ip4` expands to multiple words.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski that's true, i forgot that's how single args are handled by `[` / `test`.   the real problem with `-z` here is, as you say, word splitting of an unquoted var.  also worth noting: the test would produce an incorrect result if `-n` were used instead of `-z`.

Comment: Aside from the other problems mentioned, the one in the title is due to stdin (FD #0) being redirected from `$FILE` inside the loop, and copying it to FD #3 doesn't change that. Solution: read the file via FD #3 and leave stdin alone. Something like `while IFS= read -r hostname <&3; ... done 3< "$FILE"`. See my answer to [this previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139652/user-input-not-accepted-in-nested-case-statement/139653#139653).

Answer (score 0):

You should not mix to `read` commands and the same `file descriptor input` (FD). In the example bellow, I changed the outermost `read` do FD=3. Here's the code snippet:

```
  #!/bin/env bash

  FILE="/etc/hosts"
  exec 3<${FILE} 2>/dev/null || exit 1
  
  while IFS= read -ru3 TDATA ; do
      echo "${TDATA}"

      echo -n "Are you sure to loop again? (y/n) "
      read -rn1 YN
      echo
      if [[ ! ${YN} =~ ^[Yy]$ ]] ; then
          echo "No more turning around."
          exec 3<&- # close file
          exit 1
      fi
  done
  exec 3<&- # close file
```